# Can I get the data and formula for this online calculator?

Tags: html, dynamic

Google has an [estimator for AdSense revenue](https://www.google.com/adsense/start/#calculator) based on region and industry. It uses a set parameter of 50,000 pageviews per month and outputs an estimate of annual revenue.

In the page code, line 382 is:

```
<div class="results-numbers" ng-repeat="character in calculatorCtrl.getRevenueValue() track by $index">
```

I presume the method `getRevenueValue()` does the calculation by a formula like:

```
Annual revenue = CPM * (pageviews / month) / 1,000 views * 12 months
```

where `CPM` = "cost per mille" = the amount paid per thousand views, and I presume there is a lookup table of CPM values for given region and industry.

Is there a way to confirm that the formula is the one I've assumed above, and is there a way to find the lookup table used for CPM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer when I took another look at the page about a week later. It turns out that the lookup table is right there in the page code on line 49:

```
var CALCULATOR_DATA = [
{"category": "Books \u0026 Literature", "multiplier": "2.16", "region": "Asia and Pacific Countries"}, 
{"category": "Internet \u0026 Telecom", "multiplier": "11.23", "region": "Asia and Pacific Countries"}, 
{"category": "Business \u0026 Industrial", "multiplier": "7.59", "region": "South America"}, 
...
{"category": "Arts \u0026 Entertainment", "multiplier": "3.62", "region": "Europe, Middle East and Africa"}];
```

The entries appear to be listed in a random order. There are 100 of them: 25 categories and four regions, exactly matching the choices offered in the drop-down lists on the page. The values of `multiplier` do confirm the formula stated in the question with `multiplier` = `CPM`.